# "I wish I knew you before"

Tags: grammar

The above sentence is a song by Amy MacDonald.

Is it grammatically correct or souldn't it rather be something like: "I wish I had known you before"?

Thanks!

Comment: It's fine as written.

Comment: The two sentences are not equivalent but both are grammatical.  https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/wish-and-if-only

Comment: @James: I suggest you convert your comment into an Answer. =)

Comment: It's a song folks, not a grammar quiz. Grammatical analysis ruins the emotional experience of the song, which depends on the meter of the phrasing. The extra syllable does not fit; suck it up and enjoy.

Comment: @James Could you please explain where in your reference 'I wish I knew you before' is said to be correct? What I read there is 'Both _wish_ and _if only_ are followed by the past perfect tense [arguably the past perfect subjunctive, which has the same form as the past perfect tense] when we talk about past regrets.' Correspondingly, the examples they give all use the past perfect (eg 'I wish I had known you before') rather than the past simple ('I wish I knew you before').

Answer (score 1):

I my view, you are right, it should be "I wish I had* known you before" (had* is subjunctive). But in spoken language, especially by speakers not very trained in language matters, past perfect is sometimes replaced by past.

Actually a sentence like "I wish I knew you before" makes no sense and is grammatically wrong.

1 I wish I knew* - knew* is past subjunctive and refers to now.

2 I wish I had* known - had* known is past perfect subjunctive and refers to a past time.